# Bar plot in R: ggplot arguments imply differing number of rows:

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list object as shown below ->

```
> myaggregate
   input$AgeAndGender   input$CTR
1          Female_<18 0.030041698
2        Female_18-24 0.010918938
3        Female_25-34 0.009839806
4        Female_35-44 0.010193773
5        Female_45-54 0.009996056
6        Female_55-64 0.020024678
7          Female_65+ 0.030060728
8            Male_<18 0.028356698
9          Male_18-24 0.011031902
10         Male_25-34 0.010218562
11         Male_35-44 0.010168911
12         Male_45-54 0.010021256
13         Male_55-64 0.020191223
14           Male_65+ 0.029717747
```

Im trying to plot a bargraph representing the CTR levels(Y axis) for each value in AgeAndGender(X axis).
When I attempt a simple plot however I run into the following issue ->

```
> ggplot(data= myaggregate,aes(x=input$AgeAndGender,y=input$CTR))+geom_bar()
Error in data.frame(x = c("Male_35-44", "Female_65+", "Male_25-34", "Female_45-54",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3378934, 14
```

I'm sure I'm missing something pretty basic. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You have `$` sign in your column names. Inside `aes()` you are not assigning columns from `myaggregate` data.frame...

Comment: I agree that your column names may be causing problems, combined with ggplot's non-standard evaluation. Try to avoid column names that include important symbols like `$`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just wanting to plot the values, then you need `stat="identity"` like in the following example:

```
library(ggplot2)

AgeAndGender <- c("f1","f2","f3")
CTR <- c(.1,.15,.12)
myaggregate <- data.frame(AgeAndGender, CTR)

ggplot(data= myaggregate,aes(x=AgeAndGender, y=CTR))  + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

Looking at your comment about your data being in a list concerns me. Try making `myaggregate` a dataframe.

Comment: Thanks! I tried by changing the names to not have $ and referencing it to myaggregate and it worked as zx874 suggested. I used your code for the graph :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to plot with something like what you are using but it's a rather weird construction. Dataframes do not generally have  dollar-signs in there name because `$` is an infix function in R. I read in the data with `read.table` and the dollar-signs get converted to periods. I put back the column names as you have them with:

```
names(myaggregate) <- c('input$AgeAndGender',   'input$CTR')
```

And then you can get a rather messy barplot with:

```
ggplot(data= myaggregate,aes(x=`input$AgeAndGender`,y=`input$CTR`))+ geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

When you just put your code in, the unquoted names get interpreted as x being the "AgeAndGender"-clumn in the `input` dataframe. If you only use ordinary quotes rather than backticks you do not succeed.

[image]